# Retrieve all app bundle identifiers which can open file at given URL

Tags: macos, cocoa, uti

How to retrieve all app bundle IDs which can open file at given URL? Like if file at given URL is .xml I want to get array of all app bundle IDs which can open .xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Launch Services' [`LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType) to get an array of bundle identifiers of capable applications.

Code might look something like the following:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample"
                                         withExtension:@"xml"];

NSString *utiType = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

BOOL success = [fileURL getResourceValue:&utiType
                         forKey:NSURLTypeIdentifierKey error:&error];

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"getResourceValue:forKey:error: returned error == %@", error);
}

NSArray *bundleIdentifiers = [(NSArray *)LSCopyAllRoleHandlersForContentType(
                         (CFStringRef)utiType, kLSRolesAll) autorelease];

NSLog(@"bundleIdentifiers == %@", bundleIdentifiers);
```

In most recent versions of OS X, Launch Services is part of the `CoreServices.framework` umbrella framework. You may need to #import it in the class you want to call the `LS*` functions in, as well as add it to the `Link Binary With Libraries` Build Phase of your target. (It seemed to work OK here without linking against it in the OS X 10.8 SDK).